# Как корректно отследить фокус на поле или почему не работает условие if else?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть простенький джс, где я при фокусе на инпуте вешаю класс на родителя, при использовании первого варианта работает лишь единожды, а вот условие if не работает вообще никак и не в каком виде, еще мне интересно почему первый вариант не сработает если вызвать через `.is(':focus')`?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/grdnk/pen/abLVrEB)

Вариант 1

```
$('.sub-search__input').on('focus', function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('focused')
})
```

Вариант 2

```
if ($('.sub-search__input').is(':focus')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('focused'); 
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('focused')
 }
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что вариант 2 не работает?

Comment: @Grundy потому что не работает.... на кодпен его добавил - можешь убедиться сам

Comment: Ну так он на codepen и работает. При загрузке страницы `.sub-search__input` без фокуса - условие отработало, класс не добавлен. Все работает именно так, как и ожидалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить событие `blur` элементу `$('.sub-search__input')` и в этом событии удалять класс родителю

```
$('.sub-search__input').on('focus', function() {
 $(this).parent().addClass('focused');
});

$('.sub-search__input').on('blur', function() { 
 $(this).parent().removeClass('focused');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге добавил необходимый функционал с помощью следующего решения

```
$('.sub-search__input').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('focused');

    $(this).on('blur', function(){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('focused');
    });

    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('focused')) {
        // some code
    }

});
```